# lapply and write.raster to save layers in different subdirectories

Tags: r, lapply, raster

I have 4 subfolders in my **results** folder. I need to save each layer (4 layers) from my stack r, in the correspondent subfolder. I tried this but all layers are written in the results folder.
Where am I wronging?

```
lapply(r, FUN=function(x) {
  writeRaster(x, file.path("./results/, paste0(names(x), ".tif")), )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example of what you are doing, more or less. You write everything to the `results` folder. I use a for-loop as that is easier to write and read than a `lapply`.

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
nms <- names(s)

for (i in 1:nlayers(s)) {
    filename = file.path("results", paste0(nms[i], ".tif"))
    print(filename)
}
#[1] "results/red.tif"
#[1] "results/green.tif"
#[1] "results/blue.tif"
```

Instead you could do something along these lines

```
for (i in 1:nlayers(s)) {
    filename = file.path(nms[i], paste0(nms[i], ".tif"))
    # dir.create(nms[i], F, F)
    print(filename)
}
#[1] "red/red.tif"
#[1] "green/green.tif"
#[1] "blue/blue.tif"
```